# hereditary ring and Dedekind ring

Tags: ring-theory

On page 161 of Rotman's homological algebra book, it states that:

A Dedekind ring is a hereditary domain.

Following it is an example: If k is a field, R = k<x,y> is both left and right hereditary. This ring is neither left-noetherian or right-noetherian. However, Dedekind rings are always noetherian.

Perheps I am being silly. But should R be a domain now and hence Dedekind by the definition given at first? So R should be noetherian? Got a bit confused here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The issue seems to be that Rotman insists that a domain is always commutative, somewhere. The page does not make that very obvious, and other authors allow domains to be noncommutative, so this is an unfortunate thing that could have perhaps been emphasized by including the word "commutative" in his definition of Dedekind ring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, a Dedekind ring is an integral domain, hence is commutative

$\qquad$ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DedekindRing.html

whereas$\;k\text{<}x,y\text{>}\;$is non-commutative.